# How to know which package was installed by system?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I am trying to identify packages that were installed by the system and then attempting to find the source of the package that were not installed by the system in Ubuntu server 14.04.3 LTS.

Comment: 14.04.3 LTS? That's 8 years old and long out of support, unfortunately.

Comment: Who installed those packages? The question is very unclear. Please upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, which will be supported until 2025.

Comment: Upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS will provide you with an altogether better OS than Ubuntu 14.04.3. Like ArchismanPanigrahi stated, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is supported until 2025, and uses a better kernel and such. I recommend updating to that.

Answer (score 1):

AS you're trying to update, find your installed packages by:

```
comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u)
```

Then you know what to install on a fresh install of 20.04